# Mysql Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, but the columns are correct

Tags: mysql

I know this has been asked before and I understand the issue, but I do not see what I am doing wrong.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table(machine varchar(32), path_string varchar(12),
   base_name varchar(16), size int(10) unsigned, status_flag int(11),
   data_type_id smallint(2), PRIMARY KEY (base_name));

INSERT IGNORE into temp_table 
select machine, path_string,base_name,size,status_flag, data_type_id from table1
```

If if remove data_type_id from the create temp table and the insert statement.  data gets inserts.  If i leave data_type_id on i get the error

> Mysql Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

If i use the select query data is coming back so it's not a data issue.

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...` are you sure that the table does not exist? Before the CREATE statement execute: `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;`

Comment: Keep in my that `IF NOT EXISTS` clause is going to make it so that if a previous version of the (temporary) table already exists (on your connection) that it will be used. If the fields are different, you can run into these kinds of problems.

Comment: [works for me](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uaYKp8NQt1QQA3Pe6nKsyu/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. As @forpas pointed out I probably needed to drop the table first. So I am dropping the table if exists then going forward with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would explicitly specify column list to avoid blind insert:

```
INSERT IGNORE into temp_table(
  machine,
  path_string,
  base_name,
  size,
  status_flag,
  data_type_id) 
select 
  machine,
  path_string,
  base_name,
  size,
  status_flag ,
  data_type_id
from table1;
```

---

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae19466e19a018b3500575984260448c)**

I also guess that the error was missing comma and column was treated as alias.

```
INSERT IGNORE into temp_table(machine,
  path_string,
  base_name,
  size,
  status_flag ,
  data_type_id) 
select 
  machine,
  path_string,
  base_name,
  size,
  status_flag -- here
  data_type_id
from table1
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9dabb50739c1e1248dd10b699b288573)**